# Custom Axis range with persp in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot 3D graphs, but I need custom Range for that. For example X axis has values [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for Y and Z, both of them have [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

The idea is that I want to test if X influences Y and Z. Y and Z are dependent variables.

I tried the following code, and the result is below:

```
 persp(mat, col = heat.colors(20) ,phi = 30, theta = -30, scale = TRUE)
```

mat is matrix for the following format..

```
    V1  V2  V3
    1   1   1.000000
    2   1   1.709133
    4   1   3.278188
    8   1   5.082078
    16  1   5.753403
    32  1   5.778228
    64  1   5.783567
    1   2   1.000000
    2   2   1.789333
    4   2   3.478188
    8   2   5.182078
    16  2   5.853403
    32  2   5.877228
    64  2   5.908357
   ...... V2 will have same format till 10
```

[image]

But I still couldn't custom ranges for X, Y and Z with the required ranges. Any idea how to custom it or if there is any other ways in R ?